# How to stop one page from firing a page view?

Tags: google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, pageviews

How can i stop just one of the pages on my website from firing a page-view event when it's loaded?

I still want the other events to fire from that page.

I am using Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your trigger by adding an exception to it like so:

[image]

If it's an SPA pageview, then it's harder with how GA4 PV tag just offers an option to fire on history changes rather than adding a history change trigger.

For this case, you would need to prevent it from firing pageviews on history changes and reimplement it via normal triggers, where you would add an exception.

Comment: Will this work as its not associated with a tag?

Luckily its not an SPA

Comment: A trigger has to be associated with a tag, otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: My page views are tracked automatically with my GA4 Enhanced measurement. Not via a tag/trigger combo. How would it work in my instanse?

Comment: Then you need to turn off the enhanced measurement and do the page_view tracking manually.

Comment: Exactly. Calling it Enhanced Measurement is a stretch. The only thing it does is listens for history changes. You only need to disable it if that page is loaded as an SPA. If it's loaded with a normal pageview, then you can add an exception to your normal pageview trigger with which you're triggering your pv tag.